# Capturing media keys (play/pause) in OSX

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-events

**The research, the problems, the mid-age crisis**

There are some questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477068/listening-to-mac-keyboard-play-pause-events) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477068/listening-to-mac-keyboard-play-pause-events) about capturing the play/pause events. The solution usually relies on extending [NSApplication](http://joshua.nozzi.name/2010/10/catching-media-key-events/) and capturing the sendEvent. However, there are two problems with that: The iTunes opens OR some apps capture it before (Spotify I am looking at you).

**Damn you spotify**

More people were bored with iTunes opening using the play/pause, and [posted in the stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437058/binding-to-media-keys-block-itunes-os-x). However, [the solution](http://overooped.com/post/2593597587/mediakeys) still gets beaten by spotify (and it relies on a strange whitelist). If I open the example and press one of the mediakeys spotify catches the event and that solution doesn't.

How can I **defeat** Spotify and capture media events?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually the [SPMediaKeyTap](https://github.com/nevyn/SPMediaKeyTap) works as expected but with a small caveat:

**You have to run it in release mode!!!**

I have discovered that checking the VLC source code.

I hope this can save some time to other people.

PS: If you find a better solution than SPMediaKeyTap please post it here. So far this is the best solution I have found.

Comment: Is there anything for swift?